# How can I ask Wolfram Alpha to rearrange an equation?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I have an equation (parentheses are used because of VBA code)

```
Y=(P/(12E((bt^3)/12))*A
```

and i know every variables but not "b". Is there any way how to ask Wolfram Alpha to "redefine" (not solve) equation so I can see something like following: I tried to do it manually (but result is not OK)

```
b=((P/EY)*12A))/t^3
```

I wish to see how right equation will look.

Original equation is on picture below

[image]

where

[image]

equation in [,] I simplified by A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to tell Wolfram|Alpha to rearrange for a particular variable; in general it will usually try to rearrange for x or y.

If I substitute `b` for `x` in your equation and use the following query:

```
solve Y - (P/(12E((xt^3)/12))*A) = 0
```

then Wolfram Alpha [returns the result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+Y+-+%28P%2F%2812E%28%28xt%5E3%29%2F12%29%29*A%29+%3D+0) you're looking for: `x` (`b`) expressed in terms of the other variables. Specifically:

```
x = A P / (E t^3 Y)  for  tY != 0  and AP != 0
```

Comment: It's almost enought. Thank you sir :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know that your question was about Wolfram Alpha, that you do not want to "solve", but here is one way you could do it in Mathematica using your real question. I renamed I into J because I is a reserved symbol in Mathematica for the imaginary unit.

```
J = b t^3/12;

expr = (P / (12 E J) ) (4 L1^3 + 3 R ( 2 Pi L1^2 + Pi R^2 + 8 L1 R ) + 12 L2 (L1 + R)^2)

Solve[ Y == expr , b]
```

Result

```
{{b -> (P (4 L1^3 + 12 L1^2 L2 + 24 L1 L2 R + 6 L1^2 \[Pi] R + 24 L1 R^2 + 12 L2 R^2 + 3 \[Pi] R^3))/(E t^3 Y)}}
```